# How to get RAR files volume index using 7-zip commands (or any alternative solutions)

Tags: python, batch-file, multipart, 7zip, rar

I have some files (207 RAR files downloaded), and they don't have a proper name to refer each part/index, and if I want to extract them I should name them manually by checking volume index (from Properties section), and as you notice that can be too time-consuming

I thought that I might do it using a batch or a python script, so the first thing I needed to do is to get the volume index from CMD "7z i FileName.rar", but I couldn't find the volume index number (or maybe HEX) from the output
Am I using the wrong command?
Or maybe it is printed but I can't find it?

I attach one of RAR files output (Volume index is 18 [It is 19th part])
https://www.pastiebin.com/5cee55060c642

I would be thankful if you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with the [`l` (list) command](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/list.htm).

Here is a simple Windows command:

```
for %a in (*.rar) do @ECHO %a & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l %a | FIND "Index" & ECHO.
```

Here is the batch file version (`%%` instead of `%`):

```
@ECHO off
for %%a in (*.rar) do ECHO %%a & "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" l %%a | FIND "Index" & ECHO.
```

This will echo the filename and the "Volume Index" field from the output of the `l` (list) command for that file like the example below:

```
myFile.part1.rar
Volume Index = 0

myFile.part2.rar
Volume Index = 1

myFile.part3.rar
Volume Index = 2
```

To rename all of the files in order, you can use the following batch file.

**Warning** This will affect *all* files in the directory it's run in and the original file names will be lost.

```
@ECHO off

SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\
for %%a in (*) do CALL:Index "%%~a"
GOTO:EOF

:Index
ECHO %~1
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=3 delims== " %%a in ('7z.exe l "%~1" ^| FIND "Index"') do CALL:Rename "%~1" %%a
ENDLOCAL
GOTO:EOF

:Rename
SET /A Index=%2+1
REN "%~1" file%Index%.rar
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem is solved and even I don't need scripting as you did it. Now I got that I was using the wrong switch (i instead of l) and because "7z -h" echoed "Show information about supported formats" for "i" switch and I considered using it to get Volume Index but apparently, I should have used "l" switch. Thank you again

Comment: (@ping me if you want me to delete this comment). I noticed this. It's not really relevant to your post as such, but I figured that it may give you a smile: [gonzalu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10265174) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67155664) saying "Worthwelle DAMN IT, you ROCK! I have been hitting my head against a wall for over two hours trying to solve this. THANK YOU SO MUCH. I wish I had enough reputation to comment under your answer or to give you an UPVOTE!!"